# Querying items in a one-to-many relationship in Realm Swift

Tags: swift, realm, one-to-many

How can I query all items inside a list based on the following code?

What I want is to be able to say, give me all of the items that belong to  `List 1` etc.

**ShoppingLists Model**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class ShoppingList: Object{
    dynamic var listName = ""
    var itemList = List<Item>()
}
```

**Item Model**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Item:Object {
    dynamic var productName: String = ""
}
```

**Output of all ShoppingLists ( *realm.objects(ShoppingList.self)* )**

```
Lists: Results<ShoppingList> (
    [0] ShoppingList {
        listName = List 1;
        itemList = RLMArray <0x6180000feb80> (
            [0] Item {
                productName = Jitomates;
            },
            [1] Item {
                productName = Grapes;
            },
            [2] Item {
                productName = Oranges;
            }
        );
    },
    [1] ShoppingList {
        listName = List 2;
        itemList = RLMArray <0x6180000fec80> (
            [0] Item {
                productName = Tomatoes;
            },
            [1] Item {
                productName = Grapes;
            },
            [2] Item {
                productName = Oranges;
            },
            [3] Item {
                productName = Green Peppers;
            },
            [4] Item {
                productName = Apples;
            }
        );
    }
)
```

**EDIT:**

The following query is close to what I'm looking for except it outputs a `Results` and I need just a `List` with all of the items inside of List 2

`let itemsFromList2 = realm.objects(ShoppingList.self).filter("listName = 'List 2' ")`

```
Items: Results<ShoppingList> (
    [0] ShoppingList {
        listName = List 2;
        itemList = RLMArray <0x6000000e3500> (
            [0] Item {
                productName = Tomatoes;
            },
            [1] Item {
                productName = Grapes;
            },
            [2] Item {
                productName = Oranges;
            },
            [3] Item {
                productName = Green Pappers;
            },
            [4] Item {
                productName = Apples;
            }
        );
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fetch `Results` from realm, then get realm objects from the `Results`.
I hope below code help you.

```
let itemsFromList2 = realm.objects(ShoppingList.self).filter("listName = 'List 2'")
// Results acts like an Array
let shoppingList2 = itemsFromList2.first!
// itemList is what you need I think
let itemList = shoppingList2.itemList
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Takanori Hirobe, that did the trick. `let itemsFromList2 = realm.objects(ShoppingList.self).filter("listName = 'List 2' ").first!.itemList`